# Get gameObject released on

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create an simple drag and drop inventory and it is working pretty much as it should using the script below:

```
public static GameObject itemBeingDragged;
Vector3 startPosition;
Transform startParent;

#region IPointerDownHandler implementation
public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventdata){
    transform.SetParent(PREFABS.instance.canvas);
    itemBeingDragged = gameObject;
    transform.SetAsLastSibling();

    Vector3 zoomUp = PREFABS.instance.originalTileSize*1.5f;
    LeanTween.scale(itemBeingDragged.GetComponent<RectTransform>(), zoomUp, 0.1f).setDelay(0f);
}
#endregion

#region IBeginDragHandler implementation
public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventdata){
    startPosition = transform.position;
    startParent = transform.parent;
    GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = false;
}
#endregion

#region IDragHandler implementation
public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData){
    transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
}
#endregion

#region IEndDragHandler implementation
public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData){
    itemBeingDragged = null;
    GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = true;

    if(transform.parent == startParent){
        transform.position = startPosition;
    }
}
#endregion

#region IPointerUpHandler implementation
public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData){
    LeanTween.scale(itemBeingDragged.GetComponent<RectTransform>(), PREFABS.instance.fieldSize, 0.2f).setDelay(0f);
}
#endregion
```

My question is. How do I get and store the gameobject which the dragged gameobject is released on?

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drag 2dtexture from inventory to game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405320/drag-2dtexture-from-inventory-to-game)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how your object structure is set up, and I don't think there's enough information in your code to know exactly how you have your objects.  If your objects are set up so that you can perform raycasts on them, there is a useful property in the [`PointerEventData`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PointerEventData.html) passed to the `OnEndDrag` method.  The property is [`pointerCurrentRaycast`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PointerEventData-pointerCurrentRaycast.html) and should be able to grab an object right below the object you are dragging (provided you turn off raycasting for that object [likely with a [`LayerMask`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html)]).

If you can't raycast with your objects but instead have them in some kind of collection, you can grab the [`position`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PointerEventData-position.html) property of the `PointerEventData` and run through the list and take the closest object to that, provided it's within some acceptable distance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually... Got the answer myself :-)

```
public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData){
    Vector3 toSize = PREFABS.instance.fieldSize;
    if(transform.parent == PREFABS.instance.startParent){
        var pointer = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
        pointer.position = Input.mousePosition;

        var raycastResults = new List<RaycastResult>();
        EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(pointer, raycastResults);
        if (raycastResults.Count > 0) {
            PREFABS.instance.parentObject = raycastResults[0].gameObject;
        }

        if(PREFABS.instance.parentObject.GetComponent<CtrlField>() != null){
            if(PREFABS.instance.parentObject.GetComponent<CtrlField>().isField == false){
                lastHolder = false;
                toSize = PREFABS.instance.invSize;
            } else {
                lastHolder = true;
            }
        } else {
            if(lastHolder == false){
                toSize = PREFABS.instance.invSize;
            }
        }
    }

    LeanTween.scale(itemBeingDragged.GetComponent<RectTransform>(), toSize, 0.2f).setDelay(0f);
}
```

I am using RayCast to achieve this :-) Thanks though.